# Deploying MERN to Heroku is failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mean-stack

I am trying to deploy this site to Heroku but it is giving me an error of deployment 
here is my GitHub code: https://github.com/hazem-kamel/Guestbook-MERN

Logs:

```
 Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /tmp/build_d37d1bf6b721c463128a9d76ebc0c69a/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

       added 194 packages from 102 contributors and audited 195 packages in 4.934s

       2 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > Backend@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_d37d1bf6b721c463128a9d76ebc0c69a
       > run-p build:**

sh: 1: run-p: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! Backend@1.0.0 build: `run-p build:**`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Backend@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.AjLZ0/_logs/2020-05-24T20_24_12_312Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried several codes but it is also failing : I am deploying by using GitHub code and Heroku automatic deploy

Answer (score 0):

Install/add to your npm/yarn respectively: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

Also, preferred way while building a Heroku app is to delete the `node_modules` folder and only upload the `package.json` (that contains dependencies to be installed!). Heroku, while deploying your app automatically scans the `package.json` file and installs all the depenencies.